# Is personal check data PHI if used to pay a covered entity?

Tags: hipaa

Is the information on a personal check such as a name, address and phone number considered personally identifiable health information or PHI if paid to a covered entity?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is PHI. What is PHI doesn't change because the name or other info is on a check instead of a chart. The goal is to stop patients from being identified without consent. Here is a [list](https://www.paubox.com/blog/what-is-phi-protected-health-information-hipaa) of items commonly covered as PHI. If I had to use that list to classify the check, I would consider it payment history. Those are not the only things that could be covered. Any information that conveys the identity of a patient could be on the list. The same rules apply no matter where the PHI is located, as long as it is transmitted to or in the care of a covered entity.

Comment: @FernThomas I'm glad it helped if it did, can you approve my answer please?